# There are $3$ urns $A,B$ and $C$. Urn $A$ contains $4$ red balls and $3$ black balls. Urn $B$ contains $5$ red balls and $4$ black balls. Urn $C$

Tags: probability

There are $3$ urns $A,B$ and $C$. Urn $A$ contains $4$ red balls and $3$ black balls. Urn $B$ contains $5$ red balls and $4$ black balls. Urn $C$ contains $4$ red balls and $4$ black balls. One ball is drawn from each of these urns . What is the probability that $3$ balls drawn consists of $2$ red balls and a black ball?

My solution goes like this:

> Considering events $A,B$ and $C$ as picking up a red ball from urn $A$, picking up a red ball from urn $B$,picking up a red ball from urn $C$. The probability of picking up two balls of red color from urn $A$ and $B$ and a black ball from urn $C$ is $P(A)P(B)P(\overline{C})=\frac{4.5.4}{7.9.8}$ . Now, this selection can be made in three different ways so the total probabiblity in this case is $P(A)P(B)P(\overline{C})=\frac{4.5.4.3}{7.9.8}$. Now, the probability of picking up two balls of red color from urn $A$ and $C$ and a black ball from urn $B$ is $P(A)P(C)P(\overline{B})=\frac{4.4.4}{7.8.9}$. This selection can be made in three different ways so the total probabiblity in this case is $P(A)P(C)P(\overline{B})=\frac{4.4.4.3}{7.8.9}$. The probability of picking up two balls of red color from urn $B$ and $C$ and a black ball from urn $A$ is $P(B)P(C)P(\overline{A})=\frac{5.4.3}{9.8.7}$.This selection can be made in three different ways so the total probabiblity in this case is $P(B)P(C)P(\overline{A})=\frac{5.4.3.3}{9.8.7}$. So, the total probability is $\frac{4.5.4.3}{7.9.8}+\frac{4.4.4.3}{7.8.9}+\frac{5.4.3.3}{9.8.7}$.

However, this is not a valid probability as you can see as the probability is greater than $1$. Where the problem is occuring ? Why this method is not valid? I am not getting it? Is it because the question does not support taking all arrangements in consideration ? Does the question is made for only the specific order i.e first drawing two  red balls and then drawing a black ball? Does the question only stand valid for the previous case mentioned?Should the problem specify this that the order in which the balls of a particular color apre chosen follows a soecific order i.e say we must choose first from urn $A$ then urn $B$ and then urn $C$?

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4457434/there-are-3-red-and-5-black-balls-in-bagaand-2-red-and-3-black-balls-i/4457455#4457455), which attacks a related problem.  In the linked answer, I advocate using a Combinatorics approach, rather than a *probability of events* approach.  I advocate the same thing (i.e. the Combinatorics approach) for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

"Now, this selection can be made in three different ways"... No. It cannot.  You can select red from A, red from B, and black from C in one way (each with a probability of success).  So $$\mathsf P(A, B, \overline C)=\dfrac{4\cdot 5\cdot 4}{7\cdot 9\cdot 8}$$

The "three ways" a black ball may be drawn from an urn is accounted for in your summation.$${\mathsf P(A,B,\overline C)+\mathsf P(A,\overline B,C)+\mathsf P(\overline A, B, C)\\=\dfrac{4\cdot 5\cdot 4}{7\cdot 9\cdot 8}+\dfrac{4\cdot 4\cdot 4}{7\cdot 9\cdot 8}+\dfrac{3\cdot 5\cdot 4}{7\cdot 9\cdot 8}\\=\dfrac {17}{42}}$$

Comment: ...Thanks a lot! Just one more thing I multiplied $3$ because of the number of ways we can do the thing say: we first choose a red ball from $A$ then a black ball from $C$ and again a red ball from $B$. This is just one out of the three ways possible. Shouldn't we take this into account?...

Comment: Changing the order *you choose* to select balls from the urn does not change the probability for selecting a particular set of colours from those urns.

Comment: That's true! However , well consider an example of a different problem: Three cards are drawn with replacement from a well shuffled pack of $52$ cards . Find the probability that the cards are king , queen and jack. So, the required probability here is $\frac{1.6!}{13^3}$ . We did take the order of selection into consideration right? So , in this case the same thing should have been valid?

Comment: The probability for drawing a king, queen, and *then* jack (as first, second, and third card) is $1/13^3$.  There are 5 other such arrangements of king, queen, and jack, so to get the probability of "a king, queen, and jack in any order", you add all six together.$$\mathsf P(K_1, Q_2, J_3)+\mathsf P(K_1, Q_3, J_2)+\cdots+\mathsf P(K_3,Q_2, J_1)$$ It is only because these all have the same probability that you can multiply any one probability by $3!$ to get the answer of $\bf 3!/13^3$.

Comment: ...  In your balls and urns example, the probabilities for "1 black in a *this* urn, and red in the others" are different for each urn, so you must add the three probabilities together *instead* of multiplying one probability by three.

Comment: No no! Look in the example problem what we did was that "we can choose a king, a queen and a jack in $\frac{1}{13^3}$ when we specify a definite order" . But when we say "in any order"  that essentially means that "first we can start by choosing a king then a queen and a jack or we can choose a queen , a king and jack or a jack,a queen and king and so on" .

Comment: ...This means the order in which we choose makes it a mutually exclusive event than the former way of choosing or the later order of choosing so we can multiply the $6!$ as all have equal probability individually such as the total probabiblity becomes $\frac{6!}{13^3}$.But in this case the same thing is happening we can choose 2 red balls and a black ball in three different orders for one choice each. We can choose 1 red ball from the urn A , 1 black ball from urn B and 1 red ball from urn C . Now, the order in which we can do this is three as we can start with urn A or urn B or C

Comment: ....Also, for each possible order corresponding to a particular choice of color the events are mutually exclusive with probabilities remaining same.The order in which we choose does not affect the probability for selecting a particular set of colors , this is true . But the order in which we choose matters right cause for considering two different orders of choosing the two events become mutually exclusive. Further these two are different events . So order of choosing should matter here?